# CreateProcess() launching child applications

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to launching a sub application from the main application using `CreateProcess` function with the following steps:

1. launched a sub `.exe` program from the main without window for the sub program
2. wait for `rand Sleep`
3. then terminate the sub application first then the main.

In the following my example code for the above but the sub program running with window(in this case NotePad) and i can't terminate the sub program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

HWND                hWnd;
STARTUPINFO         sInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;

ZeroMemory(&sInfo, sizeof(sInfo));
sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(pInfo));

if (CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo))
{
    printf("Sleeping 100ms...\n");
    Sleep(100);

    DWORD dwExitCode;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pInfo.hProcess, &dwExitCode);

    CloseHandle(pInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess);

    }

system("pause");

return 0;

 }
```

Comment: @chris To use TerminateProcess i must know the PID, so how can i get the process PID in this case.

Comment: I moved my comments and suggestions to an answer. Note that you need the handle, not process ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the notepad window shows is because it's not a console application. MSDN says this about `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`:

> The process is a console application that is being run without a console window. Therefore, the console handle for the application is not set. 
>   **This flag is ignored if the application is not a console application**, or if it is used with either CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or DETACHED_PROCESS.

Instead, use the `STARTUPINFO` you pass in:

```
sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

I believe that will affect the last argument to `WinMain` in Notepad's main function, but I'm not sure.

As for why notepad doesn't close, `GetExitCodeProcess` doesn't actually end the process, it just retrieves the state. You can use `TerminateProcess` instead:

```
TerminateProcess(pInfo.hProcess, 0);
```